# How to press Home key in Window-based Networking XNA game?

Tags: xna

I wrote a game use multiplayer XNA network game. After I sign-in by a local profile, I cannot press Home key to view Guide menu Window LIVE. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to Force or simulate the press of Home key.
There are ways to do that, and one of them is to use SendKeys function

```
SendKeys "{Home}"
```

Also

```
SendKeys "{Home}", True    '
```

Read more about that here
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/339282-sendkeys-using-directinput/

Comment: Nope, I mean when I implement Guide User Interface in Gamer Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975583.aspx. They show "The player can view the Guide at any time by pressing the HOME key on the keyboard". I want to simulate my own button just like that HOME key in XNA.